# Securing internal API endpoint with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a web application where users can upload documents.

A user can upload many documents (hasMany).

I have below `Vue` file, that fetches my internal API to get the information from an uploaded document. Below is the method I am using:

`ShowDocument.Vue`

```
getDocument: function (documentId) {
    axios.get('/api/documents/' + documentId).then((response) => {
        this.document = response.data.document;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })

},
```

In my `routes/api.php` file, I have defined below route:

```php
Route::apiResource('documents', 'Api\DocumentsController')->middleware('ajax')->only(['show']);
```

As you can see, I have a custom middleware called `ajax`. This makes sure that only AJAX requests to the API endpoint are accepted:

`app\Http\Middleware\RequestIsAjax.php`

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (! $request->ajax())
        return abort(403);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Further, the `DocumentsController` simply looks like this:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $document = Document::findOrFail($id);

    return response()->json([
        'document' => $document,
    ], 200);
}
```

So far so good. Now, my problem is - this API endpoint is only used internally (for now), but as a user I can easily view the information of another users document, by simply sending an AJAX request to:

```
/api/documents/<documentID>
```

and simply replace  with another number.

My question is, how can I prevent this and ensure that only the user can view their own documents?

Comment: Add the check in your controller.

Comment: Even better is to add a `where` condition automatically attached from the boot method of the model where you add a `where` of current authenticated `user_id` as well.

Comment: @vivek_23 interesting. Would you mind providing an example? I am not sure how to incorporate this, as the `axios.get()` only containts the document ID.

Comment: You would do this on the backend and not the frontend. Can you let me know how do you get the user_id in your application? Also, does `Document` have a `user_id` column in the DB table?

Comment: Yes `Document` have an `user_id` column. In a normal view, I would just define a policy and do something like `return $user->id === $document->user_id`

Comment: So, how do you access user's ID in your current application? `$user->id` ? Or do you set in the config on the fly?

Comment: I access it like: `$user->id`

Comment: Ok, but how do you access it universally if you wanted to?

Comment: I am asking this because I can't do `$user->id` inside a model class as `$user` is out of scope there.

Comment: Also, the boot method way is here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional check. It could be as rudimentary as this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $document = Document::findOrFail($id);

    if ($document->user_id !== auth()->id())
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'You are not allowed to see this document',
        ], 403);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'document' => $document,
    ], 200);
}
```

Alternatively, you could also do this when finding the document (because it seems you are not using Model Binding), so this should also work:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $document = Document::where('user_id', auth()->id)->find($id);

    if ($document)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => "The document does not exist or you are not allowed to see it.",
        ], 404);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'document' => $document,
    ], 200);
}
```

Then again, you could implement this in not only in the controller but in a middleware, a Form Request, and so on.